# Selenium Java and PageObjectModel for finding element by id that contains string

Tags: java, selenium, selector

I have a Java project using Selenium and Page Object Model and need to find buttons with IDs that end with the String "Cancel". I tried using regular expressions also, I found a few solutions on stackoverflow that included XPath, but taking into consideration that the website's design is changing often I do not use XPath.
I also found as a solution that you can use an ends-with CSS selector:

`By.cssSelector("[id$=default-create-firstname]")` but I would like to take advantage of the Page Object Model and use the annotation `@FindBy`, therefore omitting the By selectors.

```
@FindBy(id = "ButtonToCancel")
private WebElement buttonToCancel;
```

How can I select all the IDs in the page that end in *Cancel, without hardcoding each id find @FindBy? From what I know, Regex patterns do not work as such:  @FindBy(id="*Cancel")

Comment: What is your question ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@FindBy(css = "*[id$='cancel']"
private List<WebElement> cancelButtons;
```

It will return list of WebElements with id ended with "*cancel*" in id field.